# Yii validates CActiveForm dropDownList before focused

Tags: php, yii

I enabled the clientValidation and even when I am clicking on a textField and leave it empty e.g. - Yii validates the textField and the dropDownList.

Widget:

```
$form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'service-form',
    'enableClientValidation'=>true,        
    'clientOptions'=>array(
        'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
),
```

The dropDownList

```
$models = Countries::model()->findAll();

$list = CHtml::listData($models, 'countryname', 'countryname');                               

echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'country', $list, array('empty' => 'Select a country...'));
echo $form->error($model,'country');
```

The rules()

```
public function rules()
{
    return array(
        array('name, country, postal_code, city, adress, description', 'required'),
        array('name', 'unique','className'=>'Item','attributeName'=>'name','message'=>"Company already exists"),
        array('postal_code', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
        array('name, country, adress, description', 'length', 'max'=>255),
        array('city', 'length', 'max'=>150),
        array('id, name, country, postal_code, city, adress, description, category, create_date', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the "enableAjaxValidation" in your CActiveForm widget.

```
$form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'service-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>true
    'enableClientValidation'=>true,        
    'clientOptions'=>array(
        'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
),
```

In your controller action before validate :

```
if(Yii::app()->getRequest()->getIsAjaxRequest()) {
    echo CActiveForm::validate( array( $model )); 
    Yii::app()->end(); 
}
```

See also the doc :
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveForm